# Not able to upgrade to 12.10 from 12.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I want to upgrade to ubuntu 12.10 from 12.04. But I am not able to do it. I don't see upgrade tab in download manager. These are the steps I followed:

1. Open Update manager
2. Click on settings
3. Click on updates tab
4. Notify me of a new version: "for any new version".

After doing this, I even restarted the machine, still I don't see upgrade tab in download manager. Plz help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe my problem was because of either/both of these reasons:

1. I had downloaded ubuntu using Wubi and Wubi might not allow me to upgrade to later version.
2. I had very little space available  ( less than 1 GB) on Ubuntu allocated by wubi.

Anyways, Thanks guys for all your help. I hope someone else also might find my answer helpful if they also had same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` in a terminal and it should upgrade to Ubuntu 12,10.

Comment: This is what I get when I apply this command :proxy 'false' looks invalid
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found

Comment: Can you give us your `etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` file?

Comment: plz find the file in 2 parts as comment does not allow more than 550 characters. First part:  cat /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
# Default behavior for the release upgrader.

[DEFAULT]
# Default prompting behavior, valid options:
#
#  never  - Never check for a new release.
#  normal - Check to see if a new release is available.  If more than one new
#           release is found, the release upgrader will attempt to upgrade to
#           the release that immediately succeeds the currently-running
#           release.

Comment: #  lts    - Check to see if a new LTS release is available.  The upgrader
#           will attempt to upgrade to the first LTS release available after
#           the currently-running one.  Note that this option should not be
#           used if the currently-running release is not itself an LTS
#           release, since in that case the upgrader won't be able to
#           determine if a newer release is available.
prompt=normal